# Query JSON data sharing same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Sample JSON Data:**

```js
{ 
"results": [
  {
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "phone": "555-555-1111"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary Jones", 
    "state": "PA", 
    "phone": "555-555-2222"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Edward Edwards", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "phone": "555-555-3333"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Abby Abberson", 
    "state": "RI", 
    "phone": "555-555-4444"
  }, 
]}
```

With this sample data I can display individual values from the `results []` array with `object.name` and `object.phone` to look something like:

```
John Smith 555-555-1111<br />
Mary Jones 555-555-2222<br />
Edward Edwards 555-555-3333<br />
Abby Abberson 555-555-4444
```

What I am trying to do now is select just the people who's state value is NY and only display their `object.name` and `object.phone`:

```
John Smith 555-555-1111<br />
Edward Edwards 555-555-3333
```

I tried this lovely little block but all it did was print all the names, which makes sense after I tried it.

```
if (object.state = "NY") {
      div.append(repName);
}
```

I can't seem to think of a way to only display those that share a the same state.

I'm probably searching for the wrong terms or have to go about this another way... please help!

Comment: Use `Array#filter()` on the results then do what you did for the full display

Comment: I'm still pretty new with js, could you elaborate on how this will help my code and how I would apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `=`(assignment operator),which is wrong.

You have to use `==`(comparison operator)

So do like below:-

```
if (object.state == "NY") {
   div.append(repName);
}
```

***Working sample-***

```js
var obj = { 
"results": [
  {
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "phone": "555-555-1111"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary Jones", 
    "state": "PA", 
    "phone": "555-555-2222"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Edward Edwards", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "phone": "555-555-3333"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Abby Abberson", 
    "state": "RI", 
    "phone": "555-555-4444"
  }, 
]};


$(obj.results).each(function(k,object){
  if (object.state == "NY") {
    $('#final_data').append(object.name +" : "+object.phone+"<br/>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="final_data"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My one cent solution:

```js
var obj = { 
"results": [
  {
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "phone": "555-555-1111"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary Jones", 
    "state": "PA", 
    "phone": "555-555-2222"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Edward Edwards", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "phone": "555-555-3333"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Abby Abberson", 
    "state": "RI", 
    "phone": "555-555-4444"
  }, 
]};

obj.results.forEach((value) => {
  if (value.state === "NY") {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = `${value.name} : ${value.phone}`;
    document.querySelector("#final_data").appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="final_data"></ul>
```

Like Alive said you used the assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `===` or `==`.